Bipartite Matching With Distant Constraints
I am investigating the complexity of the following problem.
Let a complete bipartite graph $G = (V \cup V', E: V \times V')$ with |V| < |V'|, where the nodes have weights $w: V \cup V' \to \mathbb{N}_{> 0}$, and a distance $k > 0$ be given.
I want to find a complete matching $M \subset E$ s.t. $\sum_{e = (v,v') \in M} w(v) \cdot w(v')$ is maximized, but a distance constraint on the right hand side must hold: Let the nodes in $V'$ be ordered as $\{v_1',\ldots,v_n'\}$. Then for all edges $(v,v'_i), (\tilde{v},v'_j) \in M$ it must hold $|i - j| \geq k$. So for example in the case $k=2$ you must leave one node out between two ones picked on the rhs.
I know this problem is solvable in polynomial time if the weights in $V'$ agree. Also i know the problem is NP-hard in the case the edge weights, in this case the product of the two node weights, are arbitrary.
Does anybody have a clue about the complexity or a problem close to this case?
